# How can I add columns from two or more pandas dataframes based on a column value and get one dataframe as the output

Tags: dataframe, data-manipulation, read.csv

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for anyone willing to help.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish and I am totally lost:

1. I have a list of ticker symbols that I am using to read in associated csv files (tickerList).  Each csv file has 3 columns labeled 'ticker' 'company' 'weight'.  I plan to read these csv files into pandas dataframes.
2. I have a list of weights that accompany each ticker (tickerWeights)

```
tickerList = ['VYM','VUG']
tickerWeights = [.1,.2]
```

3. I would like to first multiply each row in column 'weight' of each csv file/dataframe by the associated tickerWeight.  For example, I would like to multiply all rows in 'VYM.csv' in column 'weight' by .1  and all rows in 'VUG.csv' in column 'weight' by .2 (as noted in the lists above).
4. I would then like to get a unique list from the column 'ticker' from all csv files/dataframes.
5. I would then like to search all csv files/dataframes for each ticker from each row of this unique list and sum by the column 'weight'

The final dataframe should be the unique list of tickers with the aggregate weight of each ticker across all the csv files/dataframes.  For example:

| ticker | sumWeight |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | .12 |
| TSLA | .10 |

I am fairly new to python so please forgive me if my question/description lacks accuracy or detail.

I hope I am describing this clearly, but please let me know if not.

Thanks again